# vbscript syntax error saving a excel file

Tags: vbscript

I have my code in vb script. result of a  stored procedure is saved in an excel.I'm getting error in  line saying

### TITLE: ActiveX Script Task

```
Error Code: 0
Error Source= Microsoft VBScript compilation error
Error Description: Syntax error
Error on Line 97
```

-----------------this is the code pls help..

```
Dim oFSOExcelFile

Set oFSOExcelFile= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim workSheet,sFileName
Dim iRow,headingRow

'Create the Excel workbook
On error Resume Next
Set oXLIDRenewal = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXLIDRenewal.Visible=True
    With oXLIDRenewal
        'Make sure there is no minimized window.
        .Application.Visible = False
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            End With    

If not rstRev.EOF then 
'Name of the excel File to import to.

sFileName=''D:\packages\Rev&CPExcel\Rev'' &iday &''-''&imonth ''-''&iyear &''.xls''

'Delete the Excel File if it already exists.
If oFSOExcelFile.FileExists(sFileName) Then
On Error Resume Next
            oFSOExcelFile.DeleteFile(sFileName)
        End If
```

Comment: well... which line is lin 97?

Comment: sFileName=''D:\packages\Rev&CPExcel\Rev'' &iday &''-''&imonth ''-''&iyear &''.xls''

Comment: yes. That is the line. Please take a closer look at the quotaton marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
sFileName=''D:\packages\Rev&CPExcel\Rev'' &iday &''-''&imonth ''-''&iyear &''.xls''
```

uses the wrong quotes and lacks at least one &. So try:

```
sFileName = "D:\packages\Rev&CPExcel\Rev" & iday & "-" & imonth & "-" & iyear & ".xls"
```

Double check `..\Rev&CPExcel\..`